# Select one existing row order by where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like that:

```
ID | lang
---------
1  | ru
2  | en
```

I want to select 1 top existing row from my where clause. Not ordering by id or by lang, but ordering by my where clause.

`where lang in ('en', 'ru')` should return row with lang `en` because `en` comes firstly in my clause.

`where lang in ('de', 'ru')` should return row with lang `ru` because row with `de` is not existed.

This not works properly because it is sorted by "default" order:

`select * from "table_name" where lang in ('en', 'ru') limit 1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *default* order.  A SQL query without an `ORDER BY` returns an *unordered* result set -- and the ordering can change between runs of the same query on the same data.

Just add the order by you want.  For instance:

```
order by (case lang where 'en' then 1 when 'ru' then 2 end)
```

Or use arrays:

```
where lang = any (array['en', 'ru'])
order by array_position(array['en', 'ru'], lang)
```

Comment: Thanks! But I have error when trying 2nd variant: `function array_position(text[], character varying) does not exist`

Comment: @Tryam . . . Here is an example of it working:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=eaf59850afa662d1a66f2479d051f2ef.

Comment: Thanks again! That's a problem in my sql editor